# Search for a specific characters and filter

Tags: python, regex

I get a list from a source where some elements of lists are appended with newline and tab.

Those escape characters have to be removed from the list.

For ex. "l1" is a list which come from a different source.

```
l1=["12358\n\t\t", "69874\n\t\t\t\t", "25476\n\t"]
```

The desired list is l2.

```
l2=[12358,69874,25476]
```

I tried using regular expression to do that but unsuccessful.

Can anybody help me to get the result as "l2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps?

```
l1=["12358\n\t\t", "69874\n\t\t\t\t", "25476\n\t"]
[int(x) for x in l1]
```

It gives:

```
[12358, 69874, 25476]
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `.replace()` to remove characters at the end then use `int()` to  typecast string to integers

```
l2 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l1[i] = l1[i].replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
    l2.append(int(l1[i]))
```

If there are any other characters, they can be also replaced in the similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these characters.

```
l2 = list(map(lambda x: int(x.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')), l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this code:**

```
import re

regobj = re.compile(r'\d+')

l1=["12358\n\t\t", "69874\n\t\t\t\t", "25476\n\t"]
li = [int(regobj.search(i).group()) for i in l1]
print(li)
```